# awk in bash cycle

Tags: bash, awk

How to apply awk for multiple files, please? The following script does nothing.

```
FILE=/media/linux/*.txt
for f in $FILES
do
    awk '{printf("%.4f %8.2f     1.000     1    1\n", $2, $4)}' $f > test$f.out
done
```

Comment: You may find [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `FILE=` (singular) and `for f in $FILES` (plural). Beyond that though, look at the difference in the output of the 2 `echo` statements below:

```
$ ls tmp
File-0  File-1  File-2  File-3

$ files=tmp/File*
$ echo "$files"
tmp/File*

$ files=( tmp/File* )
$ echo "${files[@]}"
tmp/File-0 tmp/File-1 tmp/File-2 tmp/File-3
```

You COULD get a list of files from the first piece of code with:

```
$ files=tmp/File*
$ echo $files
tmp/File-0 tmp/File-1 tmp/File-2 tmp/File-3
```

but then you have introduced an unquoted variable which has associated concerns/caveats, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

So if you wanted to write a loop for some reason it'd be:

```
files=( tmp/File* )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    awk 'script' "$f"
done
```

or you could do this without a loop:

```
files=( tmp/File* )
awk 'script' "${files[@]}"
```

or just:

```
awk 'script' tmp/File*
```

If you want a unique output file per input file with either of the non-loop commands:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=FILENAME ".out"} {print > out}' tmp/File*
```

That will create `File1.txt.out` output file from `File1.txt` input file. Massage how you populate the variable `out` if you want a different naming conversion, e.g. `out=FILENAME; sub(/\.txt$/,".out",out)` to generate `File1.out` from `File1.txt`,

Don't use all-upper-case for non-exported variable names by the way, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).